# React keycloak - How to use onAuthSuccess and onAuthLogout events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keycloak

I use [keycloak](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-keycloak/web?activeTab=readme) on my React project as authentication and authorization tool and want to store some data of the user inside a React Context to access data like username etc. This context should update when I log in or log out.
My first approach was to use two events called `onAuthSuccess` and `onAuthLogout` but it seems that it will not be fired at all.

To test this approach I execute a `console.log`. Unfortunately nothing happens if I log in via `keycloak.login()` and logout via `keycloak.logout()`.

```
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';
import configData from './config.json';

const keycloak = new Keycloak(configData);
keycloak.onAuthSuccess = () => {
    console.log('log in!');
}

keycloak.onAuthLogout = () => {
    console.log('log out');
}

export default keycloak
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use anonymous function instead arrow

```
keycloak.onAuthSuccess = function() {
  console.log('log in!');
}
```